# Mortarboard and daily maximum

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, daily-reputation-limit, help-center, daily-reputation-badges

As I wasn't awarded with this badge when reaching over 200 daily reputation I started to wonder why. It turned out that **site association bonus** is excluded. Although the information at [what is reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) says:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
>   of the activities below. **Only bounty awards and accepted answers are
>   not subject to the daily reputation limit.**
>
> You gain reputation when:
>
> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> - bounty awarded to your answer: +full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
> - **site association bonus**: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

Don't know if this exclusion of the account association bonus is mentioned anywhere else, but this information is misleading in my opinion.

I suggest to modify the ["what is reputation"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) site and make it clearly inform about the situation. For example:

> Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not
>   subject to the daily reputation limit.

as [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) mentioned in comment.

Comment: Agreed. I suggest changing to "Bounty awards, accepted answers, and association bonuses are not subject to the daily reputation limit."

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sounds good, included into the question.

Comment: Cheers @Michał, I'm rather proud of myself for using [Oxford comma](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199098/152859)! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good suggestion; I've made that change to the "What is reputation?" page on all sites in the network.

Comment: Awesome! Maybe link the "association bonuses" part to [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/cross-site-account-associations/)? Quite old but still relevant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure, why not!